# can ${e^{ikx}}$ and the heaviside step funtion have similar physics content about the distribution of x

Tags: statistical-mechanics

in an [online video lecture,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVIlit-PpN8&list=PLNs8zPL1U25HTt3ZDKdqLj0CVOCmAmKXn&index=33&t=0s)(around 38min, where the exactly statement is at 38min28secs.)
i got one question,
suppose we have a system of $N$ particles, $\left\{ {{{\vec r}_i}(t)} \right\}i = 1, \cdot  \cdot  \cdot ,N$ are the position vectors of the particles. 
I was told in the lecture that the so-called self intermediate scattering function is defined as.
$${F_s}(k,t) = \frac{1}{N}\left\langle {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{e^{i\vec k \cdot [{{\vec r}_i}(t) - {{\vec r}_i}(0)]}}} } \right\rangle.$$ (for homogeneous system, it only depends on the absolute value of $\vec k$.)

Furthrmore, also defined is the overlap funtion 
$${Q_s} = \frac{1}{N}\left\langle {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\theta (a - \left| {{{\vec r}_i}(t) - {{\vec r}_i}(0)} \right|)} } \right\rangle$$.
where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function and $a$ is a scaler at constant value

it is said that ${F_s}(k,t)$ and ${Q_s}$ are equivalent and have similar physical content if $2\pi/k$ is replaced by $a$. But I really did not see why. Could anybody give me some help on it. Thanks!

Comment: Bearing in mind dimensional analysis, I think you mean $2\pi/k$ is replaced by $a$.

Comment: @J.G. yes, you are right. I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regard $X_j:=r_j(t)-r_j(0)$ as a random variable. Since $\left\langle\theta(a-|X_j|)\right\rangle=\Bbb P(|X_j|\le a)$, $Q_s$ is the average across $j$ of the CDFs of the $|X_j|$. By homogeneity, this characterizes the joint distribution of the $X_j$. Similarly, $F_s$ is the average across $j$ of the [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Generalizations) of the $X_j$.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! As you mentioned, $Q_s$ is the CDF of a random variable $|X_j|$ and $F_s$ is the characteristic function. We can generate the cumulant of $|X_j|$ with any order we want regardless the value of $k$. Then why did Berthier emphasize that when $2\pi/k$ is replaced by $a$, $Q_s$ and $F_s$ are equivalent.

Comment: @FaDA $2\pi/k$ is the wavelength for a wavevector $\vec{k}$. It also makes sense in terms of Fourier transforms, reciprocal lattices etc.

Comment: Thanks @J.G. for your help! I mean regarding $F_s$  as the characteristic function, $Q_s$ and $F_s$ are equivalent not matter what value does $k$ have. So Why did he said that if  $2\pi/k$ is replaced by $a$ those two are equivalent